# Three.js vs Pixi.js vs D3.js

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, three.js, d3.js, pixijs

Цель: научиться писать игры, подобные слот-играм в казино.
Вопрос: какой фреймворк лучше подходит под подобный софт?

Пример слота:
[image: Пример работы]

P.S. В интернетах полно холиваров, и после каждого прочитанного форума выбор яснее не становится. Хотелось бы получить ответ, немного раскрывающий, почему именно этот фреймворк лучше или хуже под подобный софт.

P.S.S. Прошу избавить меня от комментариев "о казино", "о жизни" и тп.

Спасибо.

Comment: Можете глянуть например [тут](https://bakhirev.biz/book/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Хотелось бы получить ответ, немного раскрывающий, почему именно этот фреймворк лучше или хуже под подобный софт.

Решайте, какой из них больше подходит для ваших задач.

---

### Three.js

Фреймворк для кодинга **3Д** онлайн , широко используется. Есть поддержка комьюнити, что важно при возникновении проблем (баги, застрял не у кого спросить и т.д.). Хорошая документация с множеством готовых примеров, на которых легко учиться.

Достаточно низкоуровневая для реализации самых смелых проектов. Есть возможность 
использовать непосредственно WebGL. В зависимости от ваших предпочтений, концентрироваться на графических процессах и железе (WebGL) или анимации и самой графике (Threejs).

Достаточно кроссбраузерна.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.z = 1;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
  material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

[Офф. сайт примеров](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_cloth)

---

### Pixi.js

Фреймворк для **2Д**, но не движок для разработки игр, это обёртка для WebGL, надо отдельно подключать нужные библиотеки (могут быть слабо поддерживаемые). Из сильных сторон скорость, возможно создавать мобильные аппликации.

Пошаговые туториалы с подробными объяснениями, как что работает. Кроссбраузерная.
Дает возможность манипулировать cпрайтами (чаще это растровыми изображениями), лёгкость в подгрузке (изображений, JSON объектов и т.д.), гибкие структуры контейнеров.

```js
var app = new PIXI.Application(800, 600, {backgroundColor : 0x1099bb});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// create a new Sprite from an image path
var bunny = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('//picsum.photos/50/50')

// center the sprite's anchor point
bunny.anchor.set(0.5);

// move the sprite to the center of the screen
bunny.x = app.screen.width / 2;
bunny.y = app.screen.height / 2;

app.stage.addChild(bunny);

// Listen for animate update
app.ticker.add(function(delta) {
    // just for fun, let's rotate mr rabbit a little
    // delta is 1 if running at 100% performance
    // creates frame-independent transformation
    bunny.rotation += 0.1 * delta;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

[Офф. сайт примеров](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/basics/basic.js)

---

### D3.js

Библиотека для графической визуализации, в основном визуализация данных. Имеет модули под определённые задачи. Детализированная векторная графика (SVG), также поддерживает JSON, CSV, geoJSON. Имеет встроенные JS функции для манипулирования объектами.

Поддержка стабильная, есть комьюнити (док. частично даже переведена на русский).

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height"),
  transform = d3.zoomIdentity;;

var points = d3.range(2000).map(phyllotaxis(10));

var g = svg.append("g");

g.selectAll("circle")
  .data(points)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", 2.5)
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("drag", dragged));

svg.call(d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8])
  .on("zoom", zoomed));

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function phyllotaxis(radius) {
  var theta = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));
  return function(i) {
    var r = radius * Math.sqrt(i),
      a = theta * i;
    return {
      x: width / 2 + r * Math.cos(a),
      y: height / 2 + r * Math.sin(a)
    };
  };
}
```

```html
<!-------- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3127661b6f13f9316be745e77fdfb084 -------->
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<!-------- Можно скролить картинку -------->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

[Список примеров](http://christopheviau.com/d3list/)

---

[Детальное сравнение Pixi.js vs Three.js](https://www.slant.co/versus/1965/11348/~pixi-js_vs_three-js)